Errors calling createinboundplan in python-amazon-sp-api
I'm totally stumped trying to migrate to the new SP API Inbound Fulfillment API at the first step (createInboundPlan).
Here's the payload just before it's POSTed to /inboundPlans
  "body": {
    "destinationMarketplaces": [
      "A1F83G8C2ARO7P"
    ],
    "items": [
      {
        "labelOwner": "SELLER",
        "msku": "GNT~300506-9-10~RubiesDisneyFroze",
        "prepOwner": "SELLER",
        "quantity": 24
      },
      {
        "labelOwner": "SELLER",
        "msku": "GNT~6061626~SpinMasterGamesSkillm",
        "prepOwner": "SELLER",
        "quantity": 8
      },
      {
        "labelOwner": "SELLER",
        "msku": "GNT~F2934~MyLittlePonyPlayDoh",
        "prepOwner": "SELLER",
        "quantity": 24
      },
      {
        "labelOwner": "SELLER",
        "msku": "GNT~HKV33~PollyPocketMiniToysCampAdve",
        "prepOwner": "SELLER",
        "quantity": 32
      },
      {
        "labelOwner": "SELLER",
        "msku": "GNT~TM15537~McFarlaneToysDCMultiverse",
        "prepOwner": "SELLER",
        "quantity": 6
      },
      {
        "labelOwner": "SELLER",
        "msku": "SMF~70604~Playmobil70596CityLifeF",
        "prepOwner": "SELLER",
        "quantity": 24
      }
    ],
    "name": "TEST",
    "sourceAddress": {
      "addressLine1": "Unit 2 49 Quarry Road",
      "addressLine2": "Ballydrain",
      "city": "Lisbane",
      "companyName": "Ardmillan Trading Limited",
      "countryCode": "GB",
      "email": "paul@email.co.uk",
      "name": "Paul Anderson",
      "phoneNumber": "07841903333",
      "postalCode": "BT23 6QQ",
      "stateOrProvinceCode": "Co. Down"
    }
  },
  "path": "/inbound/fba/<version>/inboundPlans",
  "method": "POST"
}

It keeps failing with the following error, which I expect means I'm passing in my body data in the wrong format, but I can't see why.  Anyone able to point me in the right direction, or show me a piece of working sample code?
sp_api.base.exceptions.SellingApiBadRequestException: [{'code': 'InvalidInput', 'message': "9 validation errors detected: Value '[]' at 'request.destinationMarketplaces' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have length greater than or equal to 1; Value at 'request.sourceAddress.phoneNumber' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have length greater than or equal to 1; Value at 'request.sourceAddress.city' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have length greater than or equal to 1; Value at 'request.sourceAddress.countryCode' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [A-Z]{2}; Value at 'request.sourceAddress.countryCode' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have length greater than or equal to 2; Value at 'request.sourceAddress.postalCode' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have length greater than or equal to 1; Value at 'request.sourceAddress.name' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have length greater than or equal to 1; Value at 'request.sourceAddress.addressLine1' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have length greater than or equal to 1; Value '[]' at 'request.items' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have length greater than or equal to 1", 'details': ''}]


I see body.sourceAddress in your posted data,
and it has a very nice 2-character GB country code.
I don't see request.sourceAddress.countryCode in what you posted.
Similarly for postalCode and other address details
mentioned in the diagnostic.
It is a diagnostic error message.
It is trying to help you understand what went wrong and how to remedy that.
Read it.
Follow its directions.
Supply the fields it suggests.
